# Is there an easy way in Mavericks to share a PDF file directly from Safari into iBooks?

Tags: macos, safari, pdf, preview, books

Safari loads and displays .PDF files nicely. iBooks is Apple's PDF reader app for sync'd and offline access. To move files currently, I have to:

1. right-click in Safari to open the PDF in Preview;
2. use Preview File menu to Move PDF file to Desktop (or anywhere more accessible than Preview's private store);
3. Open iBooks and drag the PDF file into iBooks.

Not hard, but a bit cumbersome for something I want to do fairly often. I could probably set up something with Automator / AppleScript, but is there an easier way given a factory install? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a simpler way. Right-mouse click (or control-click) on the .pdf and Open With iBooks:

[image]

Comment: That's once the file is available in Finder? So that's equivalent to my step#3: two clicks instead of a click and a drag.

Comment: Yah. Actually, once the file is in a directory, it just a click - slide - release to get into iBooks. Easy-peasy.

Comment: OK, arguably marginally quicker than click & drag, but there's still steps #1 & #2. Not seeing that this is materially more efficient than the process I outlined..